# What kind of color palette is this?

Tags: point-clouds, photogrammetry

Exported Iron color palette pointcloud from photogrammetry app:

R -18.696 Y  20.427 Z  -22.023 R? 16640 G?  13056 B?  512

and want to connect it to RGB codes like:

"#00000a"
"#000014"
"#00001e"

but it seems like scale with values 16640 13056 512 isn't even near to RGB values.

I've used Thermal drone to reconstruct some geometry with temperature values.

//

I hope anyone could give some hints what kind of Color tha could be?

Comment: The last three values might be on a scale of 0-65535, i.e. 16-bit RGB. Are you sure the first character of that line isn't meant to be 'X'?

Comment: I just checked those three RGB values, the bottom 8 bits on each of them are all zeroes. I think you might have some success by dividing them by 256 and converting them to hex.